# Safe/Correct use of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, encapsulation

I understand that you shouldn't return a pointer or reference to member data because it breaks encapsulation. But I'm not sure if that is what's happening in this case and I could use some clarification...

Tree header-

```
#include "TreeNode.h"
class Tree
{
public:
    explicit Tree(Tree* treeToCopy);
    explicit Tree(TreeNode*);
    TreeNode& getRootNode() const;
private:
    TreeNode* rootNodeOfExpressionTree;
};
```

Tree.cpp-

```
#include "Tree.h"


Tree::Tree(Tree* treeToCopy)
{
    rootNodeOfExpressionTree = &treeToCopy->getRootNode();
}
Tree::Tree(TreeNode* rootNodeOfExpressionTree)
    :rootNodeOfExpressionTree(rootNodeOfExpressionTree)
{
}//empty constructor body

TreeNode& Tree::getRootNode() const
{
    return *rootNodeOfExpressionTree;
}
```

My question is with regard to the getRootNode() method. Since rootNodeOfExpressionTree is a pointer, and I'm dereferencing it and returning a reference to whatever it was pointing to, then I'm not breaking encapsulation correct?

Comment: I would say it still breaks encapsulation because it allows any caller to modify `*rootNodeOfExpressionTree` without protection. But it does protect `rootNodeOfExpressionTree`, it all depends on how `Tree` is meant to behave.

Comment: There is no problem with breaking incapsulation, because there is no need to protect incapsulation. What you need to protect is *invariant*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with breaking *encapsulation*. None whatsoever. The problem is with breaking *invariant*. Encapsulation is a myth. Invariant is a real thing.

Here a caller to `getRootNode` get's access to the data `Tree` member points to. What that means is that the caller can't change the pointer itself, but it can change the data the pointer points to. I realize this might be confusing, so here is a simple example:

```
struct A {
    A() : member(new int(42)) {}
    int& get() const { return *member; }

    private:
    int* member;
};

....
A a; // *a.member is 42
int& x = a.get();
x = 56; // *a.member is 56!
```

The question is, is this data an *invariant* worth protecting? I have no idea, only you can tell.

Comment: If the object that rootNodeOfExpressionTree is pointing to isn't something like an integer, but another object of some class, you would still have to access that class's methods to change anything. So if the node doesn't give you the ability to break encapsulation, then is there any harm in being able to access it this way?

Comment: @LBaelish, i do not know what's valid for your design. You are returning non-const reference, so the caller can modify the actual data. Is it important for your class that the data is not modified, or modified only in controlled-way? I have no idea.

Comment: I think there are two problems that you have to sort out.  First (and probably initially more important) is *invariance*, as SergeyA says.  If you give users access to the TreeNode, can they change the tree in a way that messes up other parts of your code?  Second (along the lines of Galik's answer), if you give someone access to the internals of your Tree, then you may not be able to change the representation later without breaking code that expected the tree.  That's one of the big wins of STL containers -- you don't need to fiddle with them, and you can put almost anything you want inside.

Comment: @Dave M I guess the only potential for concern is if you were delete whatever is at that reference then you'd have a pointer that's pointing to nothing which wouldn't be good. The only reason I need this method is so that I can make a copy of the Tree because there's another method that returns a 'new Tree'. Guess I'll have to think of something else...

Comment: @LBaelish You can make the function *private*. Then it becomes an implementation detail. So you can have a *public* function to return a copy of the whole tree and internally it can call the *private* functions that deal with `TreeNode` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You're not breaking encapsulation any more than the user can do himself just by doing `TreeNode *my_node = new TreeNode;`  The user can only call public methods of the TreeNode, and since you're returning a `const` reference, he can't even call methods that would alter things.

So I don't think this is a problem.  By comparison, *this* is potentially-problematic code:

```
class ServoController {
    void setPosition( int x ) { /* do some stuff to move servo, then */ current_position = x; }
    int &getPosition( void ) { return current_position; } // <--- don't do this!
// ...
    int current_position;
} ;
```

By returning a reference to the member variable `current_position`, you allow the user to mess with your state without actually moving the servo.  That may put the program out of sync and cause grief.

Comment: Nope, the method **does not** return const reference.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, you *do* have to be careful about object lifetime when you do something like this.  But imagine that you're using your TreeNode to hold a parse tree for an arithmetic expression.  You could legitimately want to pass a subtree of the expression to a solver or something, and this is how you'd do it.  You just have to make sure the whole expression lasts long enough for the solver to do its work, and probably also that the expression doesn't change out from under the solver.

Comment: @SergeyA Oh, right, I didn't see that.  But the recipient still can't call private member functions or access private member variables, right?

Comment: Dave, depends. For example, 'recipient' might be a friend function of the TreeNode...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with pointers. I would say you are breaking encapsulation because `TreeNode` objects should be an implementation detail and the public interface should ideally only deal in what `TreeNode` objects are used to store.

I assume your `Tree` is being used to store some non-structural data?

Then *encapsulation* should ideally hide everything from the public `API` that is not an element, or an iterator to an element of the *non-structural* data. Think about the `STL` containers. You don't need to see the *root pointer* of the *linked list* that `std::list` uses because its a hidden implementation detail. But you **do** get to see the first *element* of *non structural* data with `std::list::front()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are breaking encapsulation, because if some code calls `getRootNode()`, it can change the data `rootNodeOfExpressionTree` is pointing to without going through the class (or even `rootNodeOfExpressionTree`), which breaks encapsulation.